# Is it possible to index custom documents in Faceted Search (ke_search) ?

Tags: typo3, faceted-search

My requirement is to index content of documents uploaded by user e.g `PDF` / `DOC` etc. Is it possible to index content of these documents by building custom indexers for the Faceted Search extension `ke_search`? If so, then can anyone provide any guide as to how would I create such indexers?

I am new to Typo3 so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to TYPO3 - the almost everything is possible CMS :-) 
For your own indexeres you will need an own small extension and then register your indexers to the ke_search. Since the customers indexeres are written in PHP, you can use the whole power of PHP. So you just need some PHP libs on your server that are able to read the content of PDF and DOC files and then store the result to the TYPO3 database.

Check the docs:
https://www.typo3-macher.de/facettierte-suche-ke-search/dokumentation/ein-eigener-indexer/

Example configuration with an indexer:
https://github.com/teaminmedias-pluswerk/ke_search_hooks

**EDIT**: You should also check the build in indexers of ke_search. I guess there is already an indexer for PDF / DOC files included.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I didn't find any builtin indexers when I installed the extension. I followed [this](https://www.typo3-macher.de/en/facetted-search-ke-search/documentation/quick-installation/) quick installation guide but I cannot find any indexers as you can see [here](http://prntscr.com/jzjpj5) I did not find that page which they have shown at point # 5

Comment: I've updated my answer with pics how to create an indexer configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I have created the indexer configuration successfully, but am getting [this](http://prntscr.com/jzu9o5) exception when I click on the search page in the frontend

Comment: Did you include the static Typoscript of the extension to your Typoscript template?

Comment: Not sure where to find that or where to include. I am literally just a day old in Typo3 unfortunately so am still in the learning phase

Comment: Check out the module "Template" in your TYPO3 backend. There are many docs for your to get startet with TYPO3 and Typoscript - keep on learning :-)